# Part of Foursquare API response missing when using VSCODE

Tags: json, api, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, foursquare

I'm trying to create a **Jupyter Notebook** project using **VSCode**. In this project I'm using Foursquare API to query venues around Seattle. However I've been running to a little problem when the notebook outputs ***JSON*** file response. I keep getting the response with only the second part of the ***JSON*** file when I set the parameter `LIMIT` to more than `20` venues.

*Let me just be clear.*

This is only happening with **VScode**. When I input the same lines of code in a **Jupyter Notebook** using the browser and setting the parameter `LIMIT` to more than `20`, I get the full ***JSON*** file response.

**Below is the code sample used in **VSCode**:**

*Imported libraries:*

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

*GEOPY.GEOCODERS to retrive Seattle coordinates.*

```
address = 'Seattle, WA'

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="foursquare")
location = geolocator.geocode(address)
latitude = location.latitude
longitude = location.longitude
print(latitude, longitude)
```

*Variables with credentials and parameters for the API request.(Note how the limit is set to 21)*

```
CLIENT_ID = 'client_id' # your Foursquare ID
CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret' # your Foursquare Secret
VERSION = '20180604'
LIMIT = 21
RADIUS = 500
```

*URL for the API request.*

```
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, latitude, longitude, VERSION, RADIUS, LIMIT)
```

*The API request.*

```
results = requests.get(url).json()
results
```

*The undiserable output: (Notice how the meta data and the first part of file is missing)*

```
['600 4th Ave (5th & Cherry)',
      'Seattle, WA 98104',
      'United States']},
    'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d129941735',
      'name': 'City Hall',
      'pluralName': 'City Halls',
      'shortName': 'City Hall',
      'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/cityhall_',
       'suffix': '.png'},
      'primary': True}],
    'referralId': 'v-1617749016',
    'hasPerk': False},
   {'id': '4b49098df964a520286326e3',
    'name': 'Seattle City Hall',
    'location': {'address': '600 4th Ave',
     'crossStreet': 'btwn Cherry & James',
     'lat': 47.60391791602839,
     'lng': -122.32999464587043,
     'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
       'lat': 47.60391791602839,
       'lng': -122.32999464587043}],
     'distance': 10,
     'postalCode': '98104',
     'cc': 'US',
     'city': 'Seattle',
     'state': 'WA',
     'country': 'United States',
     'formattedAddress': ['600 4th Ave (btwn Cherry & James)',
      'Seattle, WA 98104',
      'United States']},
    'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d129941735',
      'name': 'City Hall',
      'pluralName': 'City Halls',
      'shortName': 'City Hall',
      'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/cityhall_',
       'suffix': '.png'},
      'primary': True}],
    'referralId': 'v-1617749016',
    'hasPerk': False},
   {'id': '4e44510fe4cd394059e89099',
    'name': 'Karr Tuttle Campbell',
    'location': {'address': '701 5th Ave',
     'lat': 47.60440702245942,
     'lng': -122.33136024826479,
     'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
       'lat': 47.60440702245942,
       'lng': -122.33136024826479}],
     'distance': 116,
     'postalCode': '98104',
     'cc': 'US',
     'city': 'Seattle',
     'state': 'WA',
     'country': 'United States',
     'formattedAddress': ['701 5th Ave',
      'Seattle, WA 98104',
      'United States']},
    'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d124941735',
      'name': 'Office',
      'pluralName': 'Offices',
      'shortName': 'Office',
      'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/default_',
       'suffix': '.png'},
      'primary': True}],
    'referralId': 'v-1617749016',
    'hasPerk': False},
   {'id': '4c3f616ed691c9b6d8a6890a',
    'name': 'City Hall Plaza',
    'location': {'address': '600 4th Ave',
     'crossStreet': '4th & Cherry',
     'lat': 47.60378595075962,
     'lng': -122.33051066366723,
     'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
       'lat': 47.60378595075962,
       'lng': -122.33051066366723}],
     'distance': 34,
     'postalCode': '98104',
     'cc': 'US',
     'city': 'Seattle',
     'state': 'WA',
     'country': 'United States',
     'formattedAddress': ['600 4th Ave (4th & Cherry)',
      'Seattle, WA 98104',
      'United States']},
    'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d129941735',
      'name': 'City Hall',
      'pluralName': 'City Halls',
      'shortName': 'City Hall',
      'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/cityhall_',
       'suffix': '.png'},
      'primary': True}],
    'referralId': 'v-1617749016',
    'hasPerk': False},
   {'id': '4ddbc954091aae6b185e2968',
    'name': 'Seattle Municipal Tower 44th Floor',
    'location': {'address': '700 5th Ave',
     'crossStreet': 'Cherry Street',
     'lat': 47.60509704657094,
     'lng': -122.3301267150704,
     'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
       'lat': 47.60509704657094,
       'lng': -122.3301267150704}],
     'distance': 140,
     'postalCode': '98104',
     'cc': 'US',
     'city': 'Seattle',
     'state': 'WA',
     'country': 'United States',
     'formattedAddress': ['700 5th Ave (Cherry Street)',
      'Seattle, WA 98104',
      'United States']},
    'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d124941735',
      'name': 'Office',
      'pluralName': 'Offices',
      'shortName': 'Office',
      'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/default_',
       'suffix': '.png'},
      'primary': True}],
    'referralId': 'v-1617749016',
    'hasPerk': False},
   {'id': '598b268efc9e9467c3d48589',
    'name': 'Bertha Knight Landes Conference Room',
    'location': {'lat': 47.603764,
     'lng': -122.32945,
     'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
       'lat': 47.603764,
       'lng': -122.32945}],
     'distance': 46,
     'postalCode': '98104',
     'cc': 'US',
     'city': 'Seattle',
     'state': 'WA',
     'country': 'United States',
     'formattedAddress': ['Seattle, WA 98104', 'United States']},
    'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d127941735',
      'name': 'Conference Room',
      'pluralName': 'Conference Rooms',
      'shortName': 'Conference room',
      'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/office_conferenceroom_',
       'suffix': '.png'},
      'primary': True}],
    'referralId': 'v-1617749016',
    'hasPerk': False},
   {'id': '4a9e9437f964a5207c3a20e3',
    'name': 'Einstein Bros Bagels',
    'location': {'address': '600 4th Ave',
     'lat': 47.60389534060459,
     'lng': -122.33065690674596,
     'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
       'lat': 47.60389534060459,
       'lng': -122.33065690674596}],
     'distance': 45,
     'postalCode': '98104',
     'cc': 'US',
     'city': 'Seattle',
     'state': 'WA',
     'country': 'United States',
     'formattedAddress': ['600 4th Ave',
      'Seattle, WA 98104',
      'United States']},
    'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d179941735',
      'name': 'Bagel Shop',
      'pluralName': 'Bagel Shops',
      'shortName': 'Bagels',
      'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/bagels_',
       'suffix': '.png'},
      'primary': True}],
    'referralId': 'v-1617749016',
    'hasPerk': False},
   {'id': '427ab380f964a52096211fe3',
    'name': 'Columbia Center',
    'location': {'address': '701 5th Ave',
     'crossStreet': 'at Columbia St',
     'lat': 47.60452412230289,
     'lng': -122.33075151763909,
     'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
       'lat': 47.60452412230289,
       'lng': -122.33075151763909},
      {'label': 'entrance', 'lat': 47.604432, 'lng': -122.330763}],
     'distance': 92,
     'postalCode': '98104',
     'cc': 'US',
     'city': 'Seattle',
     'state': 'WA',
     'country': 'United States',
     'formattedAddress': ['701 5th Ave (at Columbia St)',
      'Seattle, WA 98104',
      'United States']},
    'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d130941735',
      'name': 'Building',
      'pluralName': 'Buildings',
      'shortName': 'Building',
      'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/default_',
       'suffix': '.png'},
      'primary': True}],
    'referralId': 'v-1617749016',
    'hasPerk': False} 

........ CONTINUED RESULTS INTENTIONALLY DELETED
```

*Running the code with `LIMIT` parameter set to `20` which gives me the desired output.*

```
CLIENT_ID = 'client_id'
CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret' 
VERSION = '20180604'
LIMIT = 20
RADIUS = 500
```

*Again, the url for the request. (No changes here)*

```
url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, latitude, longitude, VERSION, RADIUS, LIMIT)
url
```

*One more time, the API request.(No changes)*

```
results = requests.get(url).json()
results
```

*Finally the desired output with the full JSON file*:

```
{'meta': {'code': 200, 'requestId': '606ce68a749e75020fe96e3a'},
 'response': {'venues': [{'id': '4c3b9d165810a593aff7ba3c',
    'name': 'City Council Chambers',
    'location': {'address': '600 4th Ave',
     'crossStreet': '5th & Cherry',
     'lat': 47.603861440975066,
     'lng': -122.33006802191612,
     'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
       'lat': 47.603861440975066,
       'lng': -122.33006802191612},
      {'label': 'entrance', 'lat': 47.603626, 'lng': -122.329618}],
     'distance': 3,
     'postalCode': '98104',
     'cc': 'US',
     'city': 'Seattle',
     'state': 'WA',
     'country': 'United States',
     'formattedAddress': ['600 4th Ave (5th & Cherry)',
      'Seattle, WA 98104',
      'United States']},
    'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d129941735',
      'name': 'City Hall',
      'pluralName': 'City Halls',
      'shortName': 'City Hall',
      'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/cityhall_',
       'suffix': '.png'},
      'primary': True}],
    'referralId': 'v-1617749643',
    'hasPerk': False},
   {'id': '4b49098df964a520286326e3',
    'name': 'Seattle City Hall',
    'location': {'address': '600 4th Ave',
     'crossStreet': 'btwn Cherry & James',
     'lat': 47.60391791602839,
     'lng': -122.32999464587043,
     'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
       'lat': 47.60391791602839,
       'lng': -122.32999464587043}],
     'distance': 10,
     'postalCode': '98104',
     'cc': 'US',
     'city': 'Seattle',
     'state': 'WA',
     'country': 'United States',
     'formattedAddress': ['600 4th Ave (btwn Cherry & James)',
      'Seattle, WA 98104',
      'United States']},
    'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d129941735',
      'name': 'City Hall',
      'pluralName': 'City Halls',
      'shortName': 'City Hall',
      'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/cityhall_',
       'suffix': '.png'},
      'primary': True}],
    'referralId': 'v-1617749643',
    'hasPerk': False},

............ CONTINUED RESULTS INTENTIONALLY DELETED
```

**Progress update**.

Apparently I'm fetching the full response file but **VSCode** is not displaying the whole output.

Below is a sample code from the same request with `LIMIT` parameter set to `30`.  The evidence of the full file being fetched but no displayed is shown when I slice the file to see only the first 20 venues.

Somehow I can even increase it to `22`. Yet if I pass this threshold the problem reappears again.

*Input:*

```
 results['response']['venues'][0:22]
```

*Output:*

```
[{'id': '4c3b9d165810a593aff7ba3c',
  'name': 'City Council Chambers',
  'location': {'address': '600 4th Ave',
   'crossStreet': '5th & Cherry',
   'lat': 47.603861440975066,
   'lng': -122.33006802191612,
   'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
     'lat': 47.603861440975066,
     'lng': -122.33006802191612},
    {'label': 'entrance', 'lat': 47.603626, 'lng': -122.329618}],
   'distance': 3,
   'postalCode': '98104',
   'cc': 'US',
   'city': 'Seattle',
   'state': 'WA',
   'country': 'United States',
   'formattedAddress': ['600 4th Ave (5th & Cherry)',
    'Seattle, WA 98104',
    'United States']},
  'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d129941735',
    'name': 'City Hall',
    'pluralName': 'City Halls',
    'shortName': 'City Hall',
    'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/cityhall_',
     'suffix': '.png'},
    'primary': True}],
  'referralId': 'v-1617761189',
  'hasPerk': False},
 {'id': '4b49098df964a520286326e3',
  'name': 'Seattle City Hall',
  'location': {'address': '600 4th Ave',
   'crossStreet': 'btwn Cherry & James',
   'lat': 47.60391791602839,
   'lng': -122.32999464587043,
   'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
     'lat': 47.60391791602839,
     'lng': -122.32999464587043}],
   'distance': 10,
   'postalCode': '98104',
   'cc': 'US',
   'city': 'Seattle',
   'state': 'WA',
   'country': 'United States',
   'formattedAddress': ['600 4th Ave (btwn Cherry & James)',
    'Seattle, WA 98104',
    'United States']},
  'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d129941735',
    'name': 'City Hall',
    'pluralName': 'City Halls',
    'shortName': 'City Hall',
    'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/cityhall_',
     'suffix': '.png'},
    'primary': True}],
  'referralId': 'v-1617761189',
  'hasPerk': False},
 {'id': '4e44510fe4cd394059e89099',
  'name': 'Karr Tuttle Campbell',
  'location': {'address': '701 5th Ave',
   'lat': 47.60440702245942,
   'lng': -122.33136024826479,
   'labeledLatLngs': [{'label': 'display',
     'lat': 47.60440702245942,
     'lng': -122.33136024826479}],
   'distance': 116,
   'postalCode': '98104',
   'cc': 'US',
   'city': 'Seattle',
   'state': 'WA',
   'country': 'United States',
   'formattedAddress': ['701 5th Ave', 'Seattle, WA 98104', 'United States']},
  'categories': [{'id': '4bf58dd8d48988d124941735',
    'name': 'Office',
    'pluralName': 'Offices',
    'shortName': 'Office',
    'icon': {'prefix': 'https://ss3.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/building/default_',
     'suffix': '.png'},
    'primary': True}],
  'referralId': 'v-1617761189',
  'hasPerk': False}
```

Answer (score 0):

***It Looks like I found the solution to my problem.***

Thank you everyone for all your diligent attention in this serious matter.

Here it goes the instructions:

Go to **VScode** Settings > In the search box type: `'text output'` > Set the text output limit to `0`

I hope this helps the next rookie in line.

[image: VSCode settings screenshot]